# Загрузка файла с приложения Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет. Есть код, который делает запрос к api, ответ парсится в формат json. Примерный код ответа:

```
{
    success: true,
    data: {
        articles: [
           [
              'name': 'Test name',
              'body': 'Lorem it...',
              'file': 'http:://domain.com/api/donwload/articles/12345.pdf'
           ],
           [...]
        ]
    }
}
```

Всё это добро рендерится на странице.
Пользователю необходимо скачать файл, но при `прямом переходе` по ссылке она не сработает, поскольку `api` требует заголовки `api-key` и `api-user`. Решил попробовать создать контроллер посередине, который отправляет запрос(с нужными заголовками) на получение файла:

```
$response = $this->sendApiRequest(true, [], '/library/test/download');
return $response;
```

Код `Api`:

```
$file = Storage::disk('downloads')->path('library/e8ebaf574813227adaec1559309870/dc5a4360bd40b3393ae9/Yor6gpYzC8gEPOBogvzb8F84H1gB3znIQxqNOlCs.pdf');
return response()->download($file);
```

Клиенту в браузере выводятся примерно такие кракозябры(байт-код):

```
%PDF-1.6 %���� 10514 0 obj <>stream h���]���y �Ҁov/�d����z�64�+A�c�<��&�ɯ_���9��gz�l�  ��GoU��^�ɗu��i]�K�L�/�� �˺�M�u���˚�T���ּ�h���k�zٖ��(]�}�K�]�����=��j��iޏh���Z�c��\�cΰ�����b�f;�9����o��RRێy㼗Q�c��ǒ�v�=�K �eK���~�w    SMp�.1�9�$�x�i�m��2�1���1��k�^�4-e�uO�5�%�\����)����la����2��p�=m�y����2o����������
```

Как мне правильно обработать ответ и дать возможность клиенту загрузить файл? Или же есть более элегантные способы решения для загрузки файлов? Буду рад любым советам.

Answer (score 1):

Для меня работает это, но в переменную $file Вам нужно положить содержимое файла (не просто путь к файлу):

```
return new Response($file, 200, [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' =>  'attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"'
        ]);
```

Была у меня ещё когда-то проблема с кодировкой содержимого файла, эту проблему тогда решил iconv(). Но он поможет только в том случае, если Вы знаете какая кодировка на входе.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, обязательно попробую! Остается вопрос, файлы могут быть различных форматов(pdf, doc, jpg, rar...), как мне правильно указывать `Content-Type` ?

Comment: @Владислав если файл сохраняете на сервере, то здесь достаточно получить mime type. Если файл будет храниться на чужом, то здесь нужно будет регулярное выражение, которое определит расширение файла, и по нему определит mime type

Comment: К сожалению Ваш вариант не помог. И мой, и Ваш вариант возвращают тоже самое (по сути Вы создаёте объект ответа вручную, а я с помощью хелперов).

Comment: Единственный мой велосипед это: читаю файл в бинарный вид, загоняю его в base64, отдаю файл в формате json со всеми необходимыми заголовками, а на клиенте формирую новый `Response`.